# Service Extension not called for Parse Cloud Code push notification

Tags: apple-push-notifications, parse-server, parse-cloud-code, back4app

I am trying to use Cloud Code to send push notifications from Parse Server 4.2.0.

I am switching from Firebase Cloud Messaging and had implemented a service extension that changed the notification title and body based on the notification payload.

After switching to Parse Push I realised that the service extension is not called anymore.

After checking the documentation, I tried adding the `mutable-content` flag, which made my app crash when calling the Cloud function.

All four of the commented out flags result in a Parse server error:

```
Fatal error: Error calling cloud function: ParseError code=141 error=Invalid function: "pushsample"
```

When I comment them out, the function works and I receive a push notification on my test device.

How do I correctly set the `mutable-content` flag so that I can modify the notification before showing it to the user?

My Parse backend is with Back4App, and I initialise the Parse server like this (the passed variables contain the necessary information as Strings:

```
ParseSwift.initialize(applicationId: applicationId, clientKey: clientKey, serverURL: serverURL)
```

This is my Cloud Function:

```
Parse.Cloud.define('pushsample', async () => {
       
       Parse.Push.send({
         channels: ["channelForTesting"],
            data: {
                
                alert: 'from CloudCode',
                title: 'Hello',
                
                // content-available: 1,
                // push_type: alert,
                // priority: 10,
                // mutable-content: 1,

            }
        }, { useMasterKey: true });
      
      return 'pushsample called successfully';
});
```

Comment: try `'mutable-content'` instead of `mutable-content`

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I thought I had tried that before, but apparently I didn't do it right. If only every problem would be this easy to solve - thanks for the leg up Davi!

Answer (score 0):

Kudos to Davi, it was a typo. Using `'mutable-content'` solved the problem.